# Need to move a variable folder based on date

Tags: vbscript, directory

This is what I have.

```
stSourceFolder = "C:\Users\HIRENS\Admin\" & Replace(CStr(Date()), "/", ".")
stTargetFolder = "C:\Users\HIRENS\Admin\HIRENS\Admin\backup\" & _
                 Replace(CStr(), "DDMMYY")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' The script will error out if it tries to create a directory that already exist
' so it is better to check for it first and only attempt to create it if it does
' not exist.
If Not fso.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   ' If it gets here then the folder for the current date does not yet exist and
   ' therefore is created.
   Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(stTargetFolder)
End If
' This copies the files and overwrites them if they exist.
fso.CopyFolder stSourceFolder, destinationDir, OverwriteExisting
' If you entend to automate this script you should remove or rem out this next
' line.
WScript.Echo "Done"
'If the target-folder does not exist then it will be created.
objFSO.CopyFolder stSourceFolder, stTargetFolder

MsgBox "Folder copied"

Set fsoObj = Nothing
```

Comment: That's some great code.  Are you just showing it off or do you have a question?

Comment: its a question... the question is in the title.. sorry for the misunderstanding. The folder name i need to move is yesterday's date DDMMYY to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
`On Error Resume Next

Dim sb : Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
sb.AppendFormat "{0:ddMMyy}", Now() -1

  '-----------------------------------------------------
 TargetFolder = "C:\Users\"& sb.ToString &""
 Set x = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 x.MoveFolder ""& TargetFolder &"" , "C:\Users\backup\"

'^^^ To move Variable folder DDMMYY
'------------------------------------------------------------

 Dim fso, count, src, folder, file 
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
 src = "C:\Users\backup\"& sb.ToString &"\"
 stringtofind = "txt"
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(src) 
 count = 0 
 For Each file In folder.files 
 If instr(LCase(file.name), LCase(stringtofind)) > 0 Then
 count = count + 1 
  End If 
 Next 

    WScript.Echo "PXE Files Count: " & count`
```